# jQuery EasyUI put scrollbar in $.messager.show

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using jQuery EasyUI in my web app. After some AJAX call, I will call `$.messager.show` method to display information if there is any error messages. The error messages sometimes is less and sometimes is in multiple lines. So when it comes to more than 3 lines, some of the message cannot be seen. I plan to put a scroll bar because I don't want to set it too big. Here is what I have and it is not working.

```
$.messager.show({   // show error message
    title: 'Error',
    msg: result.msg,
    style:{
        overflow:'scroll'
    }
});
```

Please help if somebody has any way to do this or trick of doing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Dialog intead of Messager. I believe the following code produces the result you want:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = result.msg;
$(div).dialog({
  title: 'Error', 
  width: 300,
  height: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  resizable: true
});
```